# How can I use a simple Dropdown list with filtering in the search box of GridView::widget, Yii2?

Tags: php, gridview, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have two tables "attendance" with attributes `id`, `status`, `date` and "staff". `staff_id` is used as foreign key in attendance table. In _form.php of attendance I used

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'status')->dropDownList([ 'Present' => 'Present', 'Absent' => 'Absent', 'Leave' => 'Leave',], ['prompt' => 'Select status']) ?>
```

for dropdown. Now I want to a dropdown in gridview search columns with property of filtering and searching. I would like my gridview to be filtered by the dropdown list I have. So when I choose a value from the dropdown list, it should search on base of choosed value. Any help would be highly appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your question is about status field

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
        ........
        [
           'attribute' => 'status',
           'label' => 'Status',
           'filter' => [ 'Present' => 'Present', 'Absent' => 'Absent', 'Leave' => 'Leave',]
        ],
        ......
```

Answer (score 1):

add this code in your cgridview,

```
array(
        'name'=>'name_of_field',
        'value'=>function($data){
                echo $data->relation_name->name;
            },
        'filter'=>CHtml::listData(Model::model()->findAll('condition_if_any'),'id','name'),
        'htmlOptions' => array('style' => "text-align:center;"),
    ),
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for add drop down in filter.

```
[
        'attribute' => 'name_of_field',
        'value' => function($model){
                      return $model->relationName->name;
                   },
        'filter' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Model::find()->all(), 'id', 'name'),
],
```

Comment: "+1"  thanx for your help .this code also run for me with the changes      'filter' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map(Model::find()->all(), 'status', 'status'),

Answer (score 0):

fetch data from tables automatically:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            [
                'attribute' => 'deptname',
                'value' => 'deptname',
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Attendance::find()->joinWith('staff')->orderBy('id')->all(), 'status', 'status'),
            ],
        ]
    ]);
?>
```